# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, continuous and bounded function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

---

---

$\blacksquare$ **Problem:** Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and bounded function such that
$$ x \int_{x}^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t \quad \text{for any } x \in \mathbb{R} $$
Prove that the function $f$ is a constant function.

---

$\bullet~$ **My Approach:** The function $f$ $\in$ $\mathscr{C}^{0}$ and $f$ is bounded, i,e., $$ \lvert f(u) \rvert < M \quad \text{for all } u \in [0, \infty) \text{ and for some } M > 0 $$
By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, there exists a map $F$ $\in$ $\mathscr{C}^1$ such that
$$ F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t \quad \text{for } x \in \mathcal{D} := \text{domain} $$
Now, we observe that,
\begin{align*}
    &\int_0^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = F(x + 1)\\
    \implies & \int_{x}^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t + \int_{0}^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t = F(x + 1)\\
    \implies & \int_x^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = F(x + 1) - F(x)
\end{align*}
Now, according to the problem,
\begin{align*}
    &x \int_x^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t \\
    \implies & \int_x^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t}{x}\\
    \implies & \int_x^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = f(c) \quad [\text{By MVT, for some } c \in (0, x)] \\
    \implies & F(x + 1) - F(x) = k %\quad [\text{by Liebnitz Rule}]
    \\
    \implies & F(x + 1) = F(x) + k \quad \text{for all } x \in [0, \infty)
\end{align*}
Now we have a claim.

$\bullet$ **Claim:** The functional Equation that just cropped up, namely $ F(x + 1) = F(x) + k ~\forall~  x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, has solution $F(x) = kx$ for any $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$.

$\bullet$ **Proof:** From the definition of $F(x)$ we have that $$ F(0) = \int_0^0 f(t) \mathrm{d}t = 0 $$
Then we have that
\begin{align*}
    F(x + 1) =&~ F(x) + k \\
     =&~ F(x - 1) + 2k \\
     =&~ F(x - 2) + 3k\\ 
     &~\vdots \\
     = &~ F(0) + (x + 1) k\\
     = &~ (x + 1)k \quad [\text{as } F(0) = 0 \text{ and for any }x \in \mathbb{R} ]
\end{align*}
Hence we have that
\begin{align*}
    &F(x) = kx = \int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t\\
    \implies &F'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} ( kx ) = f(x) \quad [\text{by Leibnitz Rule}]\\
    \implies & f(x) = k \quad \text{for any }  x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
Hence we are done!

---

---

Is there any glitch in the proof? Any different solution approach (maybe using the boundedness of the map $f$) will be desired too!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have thought about another solution.

Say, from given,
$$ x \int_{x}^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t \quad \text{for any } x \in \mathbb{R} $$
$$ \implies  \int_x^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t}{x} \quad \text{for any } x \in \mathbb{R}  $$
$$ \implies  \int_x^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = f(c) \quad [\text{By MVT, for some } c \in (0, x)] \\ $$
$$ \implies \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{x}^{x + 1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = 0 \implies f(x + 1) - f(x) = 0 \implies f(x + 1) = f(x) \quad \text{for any } x \in \mathbb{R} $$
$$ \implies f(x + 1) = f(x) = f(x - 1) = \cdots = f(0) \quad \text{for any }  x\in \mathbb{R}  $$
Hence, $f(x) = f(0)~$ for any $~x \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $f(x)$ is constant for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

Is it right?

Comment: The abscissa $c$ could depend on $x$.

Comment: Yeah, so basically, what happens is $f(c_x) $ should be the right thing, I guess as $c$ is a function of $x$, such that $c_x \in (0, x)$

Comment: The abscissa $c$ isn't a function of $x$ --- for any $x$ there could exist multiple abscissas $c$, so it is not possible to naively invert and call $c$ a function of $x$.